# Undo bounty because question is a duplicate

Tags: support, bounties, duplicate-questions

I made a bounty before an hour to question [Code first add properties at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365221/code-first-add-properties-at-runtime) and after couple of minutes @Wiktor Zychla found that my question is a duplicate.

Is it possible to remove the bounty?

Comment: You can flag under "other" and request a mod refunds it (explaining why) **but** the the refund is not garanteed and longer the bounty is open or if answers are posted the bounty becomes less likely to be refunded

Comment: thanks I will try it.

Comment: @RichardTingle I've turned your comment suggestion into its own answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392861/308327

Comment: @M.Justin and I've fixed some typos that Richard can't fix as we can't edit comments. (beyond the narrow five minutes window.)

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218173/308327#comment707410_218173) by Richard Tingle, you could raise a flag on the question, using the "In need of moderator intervention" option:

> You can flag under "other" and request a mod refunds it (explaining why) **but** the refund is not guaranteed, and the longer the bounty is open or if answers are posted the bounty becomes less likely to be refunded